# Need to convert MySql Timestamp rank to 1 - 100 value

Tags: php, mysql, algorithm, statistics, rank

I used this [link](http://restfulmvc.com/reddit-algorithm.shtml) to create a ranking algorithm for my website. It is working great.  I basically have it done like this:

```
LOG10((s.views) + (s.likes * 2) + 1) * 287015 + UNIX_TIMESTAMP(m.check_time) AS Hotness
```

The query is then sorted by Hotness which gives me the largest rank on top.  I would like to take Hotness which is a manipulated time value and convert it to a score such as 1 - 100.  Hotness looks like this in the query: '1469612365.0402453'.  Is there anything I can do with that?

Comment: Could you do a log10 on the unix_timestamp as well to get a value much lower?

Comment: I am confused. You have that in a query as a column output, and they vary of course, and you can do an order by? If so, just use the normal `@rownum` rankings

Comment: @Drew, yes, that is a column in my select and yes, I do an order by to get the 1st, 2nd, 3rd... But I want to give some sort of score to show the user.  I have in mind the site, 500px. They rank images by a score between 1 and 100.  So I know that a user is in first place, but I want to give them a grade based on the Hotness algorithm like 95.8...

Comment: If my answer below solved your issue, please mark it with the Green check mark. That is how we roll here.

Comment: @drew, looks like your answer just gives an ordered rank instead of a grade.  I must be asking this all wrong.  Right now, hotness is a timestamp value and I want to convert it to a grade type score... did your answer provide that?

Comment: Can you show a sample tabular example of the output (well input and output) so this can be achieved.

Comment: I deleted my answer cuz there was no response.